# Anaconda Launher Spyder Error fetching package index

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, launcher, spyder

Has anyone ever seen this error in Anaconda Launcher for Python?

```
Error fetching package index
HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity for url: repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2: repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
```

I get this while launching Spyder on my Mac OSX El Capitan with Python 2.7.11. I am also using Conda Version: 3.19.1
Thanks